# Attach Command property to other control than Button in MVVM Cross

Tags: c#, mvvm, navigation, mvvmcross

I was wondering if there's a way to attach the Command property to let's say a HubTile (from the Windows Phone Toolkit), my code looks something like this:

```
 <tk:HubTile Size="Large"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
             Margin="6"
             Name="hubTileFriends"
             Title="{Binding GlobalResources.AppResources.MainPage_Tile_Friends}"/>
```

I want to navigate to another Page when i tap this HubTile and while I was looking at the MVVM Cross examples, the only way to navigate to another Page, is by using  a Command on the View's (Page) ViewModel, something like this:

```
public ICommand Navigate
    {
        get { return new MvxCommand(()=> ShowViewModel<FriendsViewModel>()); }
    }
```

So that means I should have a button somewhere on my MainPage looking like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Navigate"/>
```

Question is, can I navigate to another page without using Command and making something in the page's code behind or can I attach that Command property to my HubTile?
Thx in advance

UPDATE

```
<tk:HubTile Size="Large"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                    Margin="6"
                    Name="btnFriends"
                    Title="{Binding GlobalResources.AppResources.MainPage_Tile_Friends}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                        <cmd:MvxEventToCommand Command="{Binding Navigate}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </tk:HubTile>
```

This made it, Visual Studio kept telling me that something was wrong with the version, looked for other places or solutions to fixed that, but out of nowhere, the error disappeeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WindowsPhone and other Xaml-based platforms, the normal way to do this is to use Behaviours - MvvmCross contains an `MvxEventToCommand` helper for this which you can use similar to EventToCommand in: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/binding-to-hubtile-events-using-mvvm-light-eventtocommand

Comment: Stupid Visual Studio was wrong all the way, I opened the project again  and the error disappeared. Thx for such an amazing job with MVVM Cross!!!